# Match name: of the list1 to a name: of the list2 and get matches from the list2

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am trying to find matches based on list1 name: in list2, but as the result get the dict2 matches. I am using this with Ansible.

```yaml
list1 :
  - name: game1
  - name: game3
list2:
  - name: game1
    type: application
    version: 123
    notes:
      type: url
      name: URLNAME
      page: https://urlname.com
  - name: game2
    type: application
    version: 223
    notes:
      type: url
      name: URLNAME
      page: https://urlname.com
  - name: game3
    type: application
    version: 333
    notes:
      type: url
      name: URLNAME
      page: https://urlname.com
  - name: game4
    type: application
    version: 443
    notes:
      type: url
      name: URLNAME
      page: https://urlname.com
```

Expected results:

```yaml
results:
  - name: game1
    type: application
    version: 123
    notes:
      type: url
      name: URLNAME
      page: https://urlname.com
  - name: game3
    type: application
    version: 333
    notes:
      type: url
      name: URLNAME
      page: https://urlname.com
```

Or if it is easier, this result would suffice:

```yaml
results:
  - name: game1
    type: application
    version: 123
  - name: game3
    type: application
    version: 333
```

This doesn't seem as a complex thing based on what I have googled and what people are trying to accomplish, but I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Get the list of *names*. Then, *selectattr* test *name* [in](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-tests.in) *names*

```yaml
  names: "{{ list1|map(attribute='name') }}"
  results: "{{ list2|selectattr('name', 'in', names) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  results:
    - name: game1
      notes: {name: URLNAME, page: 'https://urlname.com', type: url}
      type: application
      version: 123
    - name: game3
      notes: {name: URLNAME, page: 'https://urlname.com', type: url}
      type: application
      version: 333
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    list1:
      - name: game1
      - name: game3
    list2:
      - name: game1
        notes: {name: URLNAME, page: 'https://urlname.com', type: url}
        type: application
        version: 123
      - name: game2
        notes: {name: URLNAME, page: 'https://urlname.com', type: url}
        type: application
        version: 223
      - name: game3
        notes: {name: URLNAME, page: 'https://urlname.com', type: url}
        type: application
        version: 333
      - name: game4
        notes: {name: URLNAME, page: 'https://urlname.com', type: url}
        type: application
        version: 443

    names: "{{ list1|map(attribute='name') }}"
    results: "{{ list2|selectattr('name', 'in', names) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: results|to_yaml
```

---

Depending on the use case, there are many other options:

- Convert the list to a dictionary

```yaml
  names: "{{ list2|map(attribute='name') }}"
  dict2: "{{ dict(names|zip(list2)) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  dict2:
    game1:
      name: game1
      notes: {name: URLNAME, page: 'https://urlname.com', type: url}
      type: application
      version: 123
    game2:
      name: game2
      notes: {name: URLNAME, page: 'https://urlname.com', type: url}
      type: application
      version: 223
    game3:
      name: game3
      notes: {name: URLNAME, page: 'https://urlname.com', type: url}
      type: application
      version: 333
    game4:
      name: game4
      notes: {name: URLNAME, page: 'https://urlname.com', type: url}
      type: application
      version: 443
```

Now, you can get the same *results*

```yaml
  results: "{{ list1|map(attribute='name')|map('extract', dict2) }}"
```

, or easily iterate the list

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ dict2[item.name] }}"
      loop: "{{ list1 }}"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [test_01] => (item={'name': 'game1'}) => 
  msg:
    name: game1
    notes:
      name: URLNAME
      page: https://urlname.com
      type: url
    type: application
    version: 123
ok: [test_01] => (item={'name': 'game3'}) => 
  msg:
    name: game3
    notes:
      name: URLNAME
      page: https://urlname.com
      type: url
    type: application
    version: 333
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    list1:
      - name: game1
      - name: game3
    list2:
      - name: game1
        notes: {name: URLNAME, page: 'https://urlname.com', type: url}
        type: application
        version: 123
      - name: game2
        notes: {name: URLNAME, page: 'https://urlname.com', type: url}
        type: application
        version: 223
      - name: game3
        notes: {name: URLNAME, page: 'https://urlname.com', type: url}
        type: application
        version: 333
      - name: game4
        notes: {name: URLNAME, page: 'https://urlname.com', type: url}
        type: application
        version: 443

    names: "{{ list2|map(attribute='name') }}"
    dict2: "{{ dict(names|zip(list2)) }}"
    results: "{{ list1|map(attribute='name')|map('extract', dict2) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: dict2|to_yaml

    - debug:
        var: results|to_yaml

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ dict2[item.name] }}"
      loop: "{{ list1 }}"
```

Comment: Wow so many solutions. Thank you so much! I am trying out one by one to understand how the filters are manipulating the lists to learn from this. I would love to be able to come up with this solution myself, but somehow I just could not see it. If you have any learning recommendations I am all ears. Thank you once again.

Comment: You are welcome! It's a moving target. IMHO the best learning option is the [community documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/) including the [source code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible), [on-line resources](https://www.ansible.com/resources), and [community channels](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/community/communication.html). See my [examples](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-examples).